# Why cast pointer to function

Tags: c, casting, callback, function-pointers

I've been studying some code, and came across a bit of code that I understand, but I can't think of any reason why it was done that way.

I reproduced the situation in the code below:

```
include <stdio.h>

void printsum(int x, double y)
{
     printf("Soma: %.2f\n", (double)x + y);
}

typedef int int_alias;

typedef void (* funcptr) (int_alias x, double y);
typedef void (* fptr) (int x, double y);

fptr pptr = &printsum;

#define A_MACRO(x, y) ((funcptr) (pptr)) (x, y)

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    double b = 2.2;

    A_MACRO(a, b);
    /* ((funcptr) (pptr)) (a, b); */

    return 0;
}
```

This is done when an event happens and the macro is called, so the print function is a callback function.

The thing I don't understand is the casting that happens because of the macro, as far as I understand `pptr` is already a pointer to a function, so why making the casting to `funcptr` again?

I'm not very familiar with this kind of construction, so maybe it's something I'm missing, could anyone give me some some light about this?

Comment: I think the result will be the same without this casting.

Comment: This looks strange... Can you share a link to original code?

Comment: Even `#define A_MACRO(x, y) (pptr)(x, y)` would work. No casting required. Probably here in this case it is done so as to improve the readability of the code.

Comment: @mafso not really, it's a lot of code and not mine...

Comment: Only reason I can think of, is when `int_alias` is `typedef` of `enum`. Then compiler would give warning if you tried to pass `int` to function expecting `enum`, as integer given might not be valid enum constant.

Comment: To give a useful answer, we probably need more information. (Btw, do you know the author?) Was the code written like that from the beginning? (Such things could be the result of merging code.) I'm tempted to flag this question, without the code it's hard to answer in a Q&A format, a discussion board is perhaps more appropriate.

Comment: @mafso I suppose more than one person worled on that code, so it could be merged code. I tried to capture the essential to the question, but if you need more information, just tell me what that I'll do my best to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

`funcptr` and `fptr` are both aliases for function pointers, yes, but they could be pointers to functions *having different argument types*, depending on the definition of `int_alias`.

The cast is dangerous if `int_alias` is typedef'd anything other than `int` (or the equivalent `signed int`).  The pointer value is preserved by the cast regardless, but calling the function via the cast pointer, as `A_MACRO()` does, produces undefined behaviour in that case.

Note that "anything other than `int`" includes enumerated types.  Though values of enumerated types can be implicitly converted to `int`, enumerated types are *not* `int`.  This is a distinction with genuine substance, as implementations may use representations of enumerated types that are narrower than `int`.  For example, GCC may choose representations differing in width and signedness for various enumerated types depending on their value ranges and on compiler options.

To sum up, then, the cast performed by `A_MACRO()`, though legal in itself, serves no useful purpose.  It could in fact be harmful.  Whoever originally wrote it may have intended it to help adapt the code to different integer types (via the `int_alias` typedef), but in fact it is a bug waiting to happen.  A better alternative would be this ...

```
#define A_MACRO(x, y) ((pptr) ((int) x, y))
```

... or simply ...

```
#define A_MACRO(x, y) ((pptr) (x, y))
```

... if the main point is to hide the fact that the function is being called via a pointer.

Comment: `gcc` uses `unsigned int` (or `int`, if there is a negative constant) for `enum` by default (when compiling C, not sure about C++), and only `(unsigned) char/short` with `-fshort-enums`. (Maybe some targets have different defaults.)

Comment: @mafso, thanks, I modified my comments correspondingly.  I was looking at the wrong documentation when I made my original comments.